# np.average of word vectors

Tags: python, numpy

I have this dictionary that contains words as keys and their vectors as values.

```
my_dict = {'new': array([ 6.77980e-02, -2.07800e-02, -1.22845e-01, 1.75853e-01,  1.49210e-02]), 
           'its': array([ 7.85300e-03, -8.81160e-02,  2.60125e-01,  1.77740e-02, -1.09075e-011])}
```

I would like to calculate the element-wise average of the vectors for these given words using `np.average()`. The result should be a `np.ndarray`.

This is my attempt:

```
average = [np.average(my_dict[x], axis=None) for x in self.my_dict]
```

Comment: Did your attempt work? Was there an error?

Comment: It returned a list, not an np.ndarray.

Comment: So your question is how to turn a list into an array?

Comment: Yes, or what should I add to my attempt to return an ndarray.

Comment: @SayedSabry _It returned a list, not an np.ndarray._ That's no surprise, since you're using a list comprehension, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that you calculate one average over all the values (rather than collect a set of nonsense average for each individual vector), try:

```
np.average(list(my_dict.values()))
```

(If it doesn't return the shape you expect, try each explicit `axis=` possibility.)